# SQL parametric columns in ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

Why can you not use parameters in an SQL statement as the column name? I found that out after two hours of thinking what the problem could be. The only way it seemed possible was by doing it in a way it could be vulnerable to SQL injections (which for me wasn't a problem because the parameters are generated serverside).

This works:

```
string cmdgetValues = "SELECT " + column + " FROM user WHERE " + filterColumn + " = @filter";
MySqlCommand getValues = new MySqlCommand(cmdgetValues, connectionDB);
getValues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filterValue);
```

This doesn't work:

```
string cmdgetValues = "SELECT @column FROM user WHERE @filterColumn = @filter";
MySqlCommand getValues = new MySqlCommand(cmdgetValues, connectionDB);
getValues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", column);
getValues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filterColumn", filterColumn);
getValues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", filterValue);
```

Why is this? And is it intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `select` columns are fundamental query

You can't parameterise the fundamental query, so you have to build the query at the code.

If you want to decide the query columns runtime maybe you can try to use [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in Mysql.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, even though I despise 'coding' in SQL itself.